# How do I monitor memcached evictions?

Tags: web-server, memcached, cache

How do I monitor memcached to know if / how many evictions are occurring, and how much memory is used/free.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$telnet ip_of_memcached_host 11211 or $nc ip_of_memcached_host 11211

```
stats
STAT pid 117
...
STAT limit_maxbytes 67108864
....
STAT evictions 0
END

stats slabs
....
STAT total_malloced 30234456
END
```

or use favorite programming language api for memcached